# Trying to iterate over a model in Django with class based views but getting the error Project object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I used the following code for models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    clientid = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
    def get_absolute_url(self): # new
        return reverse('projectdetail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

This is the code for views.py

```
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'projectdetail.html'
    fields='__all__'
```

And this is the template i am using

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    
    {% if project %}
       There are {{ project|length }} records:
    {% for i in project %}
    <div class="project-entry">
        <h2>{{ i.id }}</h2>
        <p>{{ i.name }} </p>
        <p>{{ i.description }} </p>
        <p>{{ i.clientid }} </p>
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   There are no records in the system
{% endif %}
    </div>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

I get the error

```
TypeError at /client/1/projectexisting
'Project' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://02ccd1dfc89b4b71b62f894adef16c07.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/client/1/projectexisting
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'Project' object is not iterable
Exception Location: /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 165
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.10
Python Path:    
['/home/ec2-user/environment/cons_mgmt/cons_mgmt',
 '/usr/lib64/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 20 Jul 2021 19:55:29 -0600
Error during template rendering
In template /home/ec2-user/environment/cons_mgmt/cons_mgmt/templates/base.html, error at line 6

'Project' object is not iterable
```

---

I am able to see data if i take out the for loop but then i am just able to see the first entry and the second entry is in another clients page.

Comment: This is a detail view, so unless you overwrite the context to provide a list of projects, you can only work on one object. How did you pass `project` to the template?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am not sure about. In the same project i have iterated through the clients table using something like this
```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for client in object_list %}
    <div class="client-entry">
        <h2><a href="{% url 'clientdetail' client.pk %}">{{ client.id }}</a></h2>
        <p>{{ client.client_name }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```
but i am not sure how to do the same for another model in the same application using class based views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to explicitly send the context into the template so that the movement is transparent... Something like this,

```
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
  model = Project
  template_name = 'projectdetail.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['project'] = Project.objects.all()    
    return context
```

Now you can iterate through the project objects ...

Answer (score 0):

keep your `models.py` and **template html** unchanged and replace the `views.py` with the following code [don't forget to keep backup], then try to execute. Let me know if it works for you.

```
#views.py
from .models import Project
def ProjectDetailView(request):
    projectdetails = Project.objects.all()
    context = {
        'project': projectdetails
    }
    return render(request, 'projectdetail.html', context)
```